# How do You know which class a thread is instantiated from in Java

Tags: java, jvm

I use jstack, below is about a thread's(pool-60-thread-455) stack info,
I used the default thread name,
how can I get the Class where the thread(pool-60-thread-455) is instantiated?

```
"pool-60-thread-455" #1665229 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9ebc3f0000 nid=0xb603 waiting on condition [0x00007f9e34cc4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000076957aae8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The thread has been instantiated in a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @Holger yes, any way to know where the ThreadPoolExecutor is instantiated?

Comment: Not from this stack trace. But ordinary application don’t create lots of thread pools. Just search the code for that single spot.

Comment: @Holger Our application has more than 50 thread pools, so I want to know where is the thread pool instantiated.

Comment: Is there any way or tool to know where it's from, for example the hprof file?

Comment: This sounds like a fundamental problem with the application design. Or a lack of understanding about the purpose of thread pools. Anyway, every heap dup analysis tool can tell you which thread pools exist and who is holding a reference to it. That’s not exactly the same as “who created it“, but usually, the creator is holding a reference to its creation.